# PassportJS difference between authenticate() and req.login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, passport.js

I am currently learning backend development and authentication with node, express and passport.

The ressource I am using uses the following code:

```
app.post("/login",(req,res") => {
    //Create user model here
    ...
    req.login(user, (err) => {
       ...
    }
})
```

However, I found that simply writing

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "/login" }), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/secret");
})
```

Leads to the same result. To be honest in my mind login is equal to authentication. The PassportJS documentation mentions that both methods set req.user.

So my question is: What is the difference and when would you use which / how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we should be looking for differences. Because the two parts you mentioned are complementary. According to your own passport site definition:

Passport exposes a `login()` function on `req` (also aliased as `logIn()`) that can be used to establish a login session.

```
req.login(user, function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  return res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

When the login operation completes, user will be assigned to `req.user`.

Note: `passport.authenticate()` middleware invokes `req.login()` automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which `req.login()` can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.

finally you can read this link [Understanding passport.js authentication flow](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/)